# Data sent from flask not received from react

Tags: html, reactjs, json, flask, web

I'm using flask as the backend and the database is using firebase. I want to get the data sent by app.py from React, but it keeps failing.

app.py

```
@app.route("/StoreListView")
def list_stores():
    storedata = DB.get_store() #read the table
    tot_count = len(storedata)
    return render_template(
    "index.html",
    storedatas=storedata.items(),
    total=tot_count)
```

StoreListView.js

```
function Stores(){
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/StoreListView", {
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(jsonData => {
            console.log(jsonData)})
        .catch(
            (err) => console.log(err))
    }, [])
}
```

I see this error.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
I think it's a problem to render html in the list_stores function... but if I just do the return stored data, the front screen coded with the react does not come out and the data is just printed out...

Comment: what might make sense in your case is to create separate Flask routes for your functions. one can render the html, and another can be fetched with JS and return your JSON data.

Comment: @AudioBaton I simply created two functions under /StoreListView routing and it results SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype"...is not valid JSON error again...

Comment: if you use that same route, every time you hit it, it will return the HTML, which is not what you want. so it may be better to create an entirely new route - not just a new function for the same route.

Comment: @AudioBaton Oh, now I understand. Thank you so much! I solved the problem based on the advice you gave me. After using different routing URL, the problem no longer occurs.